# vertically and horizontally cell

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

I want to enter text in a table with a fixed column width. This text should be centered vertically and horizontally. In addition, I would like to have a manual line break in some cells.

This is what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|L{2cm}|C{4cm}|C{2cm}|}
\hline
5 min & text & Text, Text, Text, Text, Text & a \newline b &a\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]
The third cell should be left and the fourth should be centered with a manual line break. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For example  `\makecell[b]{a \\ b}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

By use of `tabularray` package this is easy to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{Q[c,m, wd=2cm]} X[c,m, wd=4cm] X[c,m, wd=2cm]}
             }
5 min & text & Text, Text, Text, Text, Text & {a\\ b} & a   \\
\end{tblr}

or maybe:

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{X[c,m]} X[2, c,m] X[c,m]}  % <---
             }
5 min & text & Text, Text, Text, Text, Text & {a\\ b} & a   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```